# Ubuntu 18.04 setup clang++

Tags: c++, ubuntu-18.04, clang++

How do I properly setup clang to use c++ std library on Ubuntu 18.04?
I have installed a bunch of libraries suggested in other threads
but without success. I also have two gcc compilers (7,9) installed and I make
use of update-alternative to switch between them. Also Clang-6, Clang-9 and llvm-9
are installed.

Some libraries I installed

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-9-dev
sudo apt install libc++-9-dev
sudo apt install g++-7-multilib  
sudo apt install g++-9-multilib
```

I think there more but the result stayed the same.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

Compiling with

```
clang++-9 hello_world.cpp
clang++ hello_world.cpp
clang++-9 -stdlib=libstdc++ hello_world.cpp
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ hello_world.cpp
```

All produce

```
hello_world.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
```

I found a bunch of posts on this topic, but most of them were on Windows or macOS
or 8 years old. There was also [this](https://gatowololo.github.io/blog/clangmissingheaders/) blog post. I am probably missing something
very obvious and was hoping maybe someone could point me into the right direction.

I installed clang with the following way, but I don't rember the exact order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt install clang libclang-dev
sudo apt-get install libclang-9-dev 
sudo apt-get install clang-9
sudo apt-get install clang++-9
```

As in the comments suggested tried to compile with
`clang++ -v hello_world.cpp` given the following output:

```
$ clang++ hello_world.cpp -v 
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello_world.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/include/clang/6.0.0/include/ -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /mnt/My_Linux_Files/C++/test2/src -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/hello_world-0f22e3.o -x c++ hello_world.cpp
clang -cc1 version 6.0.0 based upon LLVM 6.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/clang/6.0.0/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/include/clang/6.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
hello_world.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

and with clang++-9:

```
$ clang++-9 hello_world.cpp -v 
clang version 9.0.0-2~ubuntu18.04.2 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-9/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello_world.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/clang/9.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/clang/9.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /mnt/My_Linux_Files/C++/test2/src -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/hello_world-9f4c00.o -x c++ hello_world.cpp
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 based upon LLVM 9.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-9/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
hello_world.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The line:

```
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
```

confuses me, does clang think that gcc-10 is installed? Because I don't
think it is:

```
$ find /usr/ -iname "*gcc-10*"
/usr/share/gcc-10
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base
/usr/share/doc/libgcc-10-dev
$
```

**Solution**

As in the comments suggested, installing libstdc++-10 solved my issue

Comment: Don't use -stdlib=libstdc++ in clang++ invocation.

Comment: To debug, I would add a `-v` to the invocation. It will print the search paths where clang looks for library headers.

Comment: How did you install clang? Using the `clang` and `clang-9` packages?

Comment: I don't see any `libstdc++-9` package in Ubuntu 18.04 repos... how did you install it?

Comment: @dyp Thanks for the comments, I tried to answer your question in the edit.

Comment: presumably the clang you've installed from `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` is hard coded to use gcc 10's include paths so you'll need to install gcc and libstdc++ 10 to make it work

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ might be a better place to seek help

Comment: @AlanBirtles That solved my issue, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 20.04, I setup [by](https://asciinema.org/a/Zrf4zg0sw6Zkj9WEHI7G8LGcx):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clang
```

And then I compile & run a test app by:

```
clang++ -o smeagol smeagol.cpp
./smeagol
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install a specifc version of g++ on your system, because clang++ does not come with its own set of headers. For Ubuntu 18.04, do it by invoking: `sudo apt install g++-8`.  Please see this nice article:

[Clang++ missing C++ header?](https://gatowololo.github.io/blog/clangmissingheaders/)